# Why is this horizontal asymptote present and how do I immediately see that from the equation?

Tags: asymptotics, rational-functions

This may seem like a stupid question, and I do feel like I should know this.

I have been given a simple curve with the following equation and was asked to state the equation of the asymptote of the curve. $$y=\frac{x+1}{x^2+3}$$
I've now discovered that there is an asymptote at *$y=0$* but cannot see why this is the case just from looking at the equation.

**What about this equation tells us that the x-axis is an asymptote to the curve?**

Comment: You can reason that $x+1 \approx x$ for large $x$, as well as $x^2 + 3 \approx x^2$, also for large $x$. Thus $\frac{x + 1}{x^2 + 3} \approx \frac{x}{x^2} \approx \frac{1}{x} \approx 0$, still for large $x$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because $${\lim}_{x \rightarrow +\infty} \frac{x+1}{x^2+3} = 0$$ and$${\lim}_{x \rightarrow -\infty} \frac{x+1}{x^2+3} = 0.$$

Generally, if limit of a function is $c$ as $x$ tends to infinity, then graph of this function has horizontal asymptote $y=c$.